# How to use the stats4 package to compute the MLEs

Tags: r, mle, error-messaging

I want to write an R-code to compute the MLEs of (µ; σ2; λ)  try initial values λ = 0.5、.... I'm trying to run the following code in R, but I'm getting an error I'm not sure what part of the formula is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(stats4)
obs.loglik4 = function(y,theta)
{
  mu=theta[1]
  sig2=theta[2]
  lambda = theta[3]
  n = length(y)
  loglik = -0.5*n*log(2*pi)-0.5*n*log(sig2)-
    sum(((y^lambda-1)/lambda-mu)^2)/(2*sig2)+(lambda-1)*sum(log(y))
  return(loglik)
}
mle.4=mle(minuslogl=obs.loglik4,start=c(1,1,0.5))
##Error in mle(minuslogl = obs.loglik4, start = c(1, 1, 0.5)) : 
  Mismatch in length of start values
mle.4=mle(minuslogl=obs.loglik4,start=list(mu=mean(y),sig2=var(y),lambda=0.5))
##Error in l2v(start) : 
  some named values are not arguments to the supplied log-likelihood
```

Comment: Please post data with `dput(y)` or if it's too big with `dput(head(y, 30))`.

Comment: head(y)
[1] 0.15 0.09 0.18 0.10 0.05 0.12

Answer (score 2):

The log likelihood function should be a function only of the variables you are looking to estimate. I wasn't going to debug your likelihood function, but here is a modification with printing of intermediate results.

```
library(stats4)
y <-c(0.15, 0.09, 0.18, 0.10, 0.05, 0.12)
nobs <- length(y)
obs.loglik4 = function(mu,sig2,lambda)
{
  n = length(y)
  loglik = -0.5*n*log(2*pi)-0.5*n*log(sig2)-
    sum(((y^lambda-1)/lambda-mu)^2)/(2*sig2)+(lambda-1)*sum(log(y))
  cat( mu, sig2, lambda, loglik, "\n", sep=", ")
  return(loglik)
}
mle.4=mle(minuslogl=obs.loglik4,
          start=list(mu=1,sig2=1, lambda=0.5), nobs=nobs, 
          lower=list(sig2=0))
```

I had to limit `sig2` to be greater than zero, but it ends up at zero anyway and fails.